# Replace old image with new image in c# winform PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to zoom an image in a picture box:

```
private void pe_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        var pe = (PictureEdit)sender;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pe.Image, imgx, imgy);
        }
```

But the image box picture is not updated.Actually a new Image is drawing over the old image.The old image is still existing.When I pan the new image i can see the old image behind it.

Comment: clear the graphics before you draw `e.Graphics.Clear(pe.BackColor);`

Comment: Note that the usualy way to zoom a PictureBox is setting its SizeMode=Zoom and changing its size, usually after placing the PB in an Autscroll Panel.. - Also drawing the whole image in each Paint event looks rather expensive..